# When My root view goes to another View, is there a way for that view to make changes to the root View?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My root view has a button called update that is hidden, and a class called cHome.
When the user exits the RootView and goes to another View I call cEdit and has a class called cEdit.  Is there a way for this view to set the hidden state of the update button on my rootview?, so when it calls
`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
to return to the root view, the update button will have the new hidden state?

to return to the root view, the update button will have the new state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way to do what you want, you can implement you own delegate.

For example :

you create a new class file in the .h you add this code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ClassNameDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void) tellUpdateButtonToHide;

@end


@interface ClassNameViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak,nonatomic)  id <ClassNameDelegate>delegate;
```

you create your own delegate, and you have to add a property, if you like to get access to the protocol

in your .m file i just add a button in the other controller (not the rootVc) that will update the rootController

```
- (IBAction)tellUpdateButtonToHide:(id)sender {

   [self.delegate tellUpdateButtonToHide];

}
```

in your rootVC .h file you import the delegateClass

```
#import "ClassNameViewController.h"

@interface RootVcViewController : UIViewController<ClassNameViewControllerDelegate>
```

and in your rootVc .m file you implement the method tellUpdateButtonToHide;

```
- (void)tellUpdateButtonToHide{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   [self.updateButton setHidden:NO];
 }
```

and in your prepareForSegue

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"da"] ) {
  ClassNameViewController *vc =(ClassNameViewController   *)segue.destinationViewController;
    [vc setDelegate:self];
}
```

Hope it work for you

Comment: this way you can also pass data from the other VC back to the root Controller

Answer (score 0):

On your root view controller, you can do something as simple as this: That way, when you return to the root view controller when you later call: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` the button will no longer be hidden.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    self.update.hidden = NO;
}
```